# javascript playing a sound not working on chrome for android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, audio

I'm using this code to play a notification sound when a message is received it works fine on chrome and firefox for pc but not working on chrome for android (didn't test it on firefox nor safari for mobile phones). Is there something wrong with it or there's a better code that works cross browsers?

```
$.post('ajax/getMsgs.php').done(function () {
  var audio = new Audio('noti.mp3');
  audio.play();
  //message displaying code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think its a audio codec related problem. I have similar problem in a website project and my deal was to play mp3/ogg file based on detected platform/browser.

Not all platforms/browsers accept all audio codec.

If i can locate this project i can post a sample.